# How to use special characters in text for CURL functions

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have integrated SMS gateway and using curl functions to send SMS. In the text which I am sending I have a `'@' symbol` because of which curl function is failed.

My text is

```
$smsbody = "A new user has logged in\nEmail: testemail@gmail.com";
```

Below is my code:

```
       $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
        \"Text\": \"$smsbody\",
        \"Number\": \"$tomobile\",
        \"SenderId\": \"Example\",
        \"DRNotifyUrl\": \"https://www.example.com\",
        \"DRNotifyHttpMethod\": \"POST\",
        \"Tool\": \"API\"
        }");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: ".$smsauthor
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

If I remove '@' symbol then I am able to send message successfully. For the messages with '@' symbol, message is getting failed.
How to encode the symbol '@' or what could be the alternative for this problem?

Comment: Not sure if it will help but maybe try to escape it `\@`

Comment: Use `urlencode` on the values. I also haven't seen the POSTFIELDS sent that way. It looks like you are manually creating JSON, maybe `json_encode` would be a better route.

Answer (score 2):

Use **curl_escape ( resource $ch , string $str )**. [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-escape.php)

> This function URL encodes the given string according to » [RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986).

Using:

```
<?php
// Create a curl handle
$ch = curl_init();

// Escape a string used as a GET parameter
$location = curl_escape($ch, 'Hofbräuhaus / München');
// Result: Hofbr%C3%A4uhaus%20%2F%20M%C3%BCnchen

// Compose an URL with the escaped string
$url = "http://example.com/add_location.php?location={$location}";
// Result: http://example.com/add_location.php?location=Hofbr%C3%A4uhaus%20%2F%20M%C3%BCnchen

// Send HTTP request and close the handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl

_close($ch);
?>
```